# I can write to SQL but reading comes back with nothing

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am quite new to coding and had a go a few months back before picking up again this week. The code I previously had working on an older host now does not seem to work with all of the mySQL information not being populated! The page conects to the server as I have tried putting errors in the connection which it picks up yet I cannot get any thing back for a count of rows or to populate my drop down box. I have pasted my code below so you can see any obvious mistakes. My other codes seem to be able to write to the table with no issue.

Thanks,

Chris

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Create a new team</title> 
</head> 
<body>

<form action="cteam.php" method="post">


<?php
   $dbserver='localhost';
   $dbusername='******';
   $dbpassword='******';
   $dbname='*******';
   $con = mysql_connect("$dbserver","$dbusername","$dbpassword");

 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }  


$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM Name");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total1 = $row[0];
echo "Current No. of registered Teams: " . $total1;
mysql_close($con);
?>

<br>
Team Full Name: <input type="text" name="longname">
<br>
Team Short Name: <input type="text" name="shortname">
<br>
Link to Logo: <input type="text" name="logo">
<br>
Select Rink or Press Create new Venue link:
<br>

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM Rink";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="venue">
<?php

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['Name'];?>"> <?php echo $line['Name'];?> </option>

<?php
}
?>
</select>   <a href="http://beerleague.co.uk/pics/cvenue1.html">Create New Venue!</a>  
<br>
Website address: <input type="text" name="website">
<br>
Twitter: <input type="text" name="twitter">
<br>
Facebook: <input type="text" name="facebook">
<br>
Link to image of home shirt: <input type="text" name="home_shirt">
<br>
Link to image of away shirt: <input type="text" name="away_shirt">
<br>
Link to image of Alt  shirt: <input type="text" name=alt_shirt">
<br>
Team Bio: <input type="text" name="blurb">
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are learning to program, you should NOT be using `mysql_*` methods as they are deprecated.  I would suggest using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` shouldn't be used in new code because it's been deprecated, is dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) has a number of recommendations as to how to keep your application up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies! I have little coding experience so everything I am doing is literally from googling phrases such as how to read from mysql etc. I will have another play tomorrow and see if I can get the above working then look at the new languages! Best to learn the right way first I guess!

Comment: Ahh well I have just tried without that line of code to no effect and checking the server details it is now running mysqli so I take it this is why my code does not work?
Server Details:
cpsrvd 11.40.0.19
Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.96
PHP extension: mysqli

Answer (score 4):

You are closing your DB connection after the first query and not re-establishing a new one.  You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also use `mysql_select_db` or specify the db.name in the query

```
select count(1) FROM DbName.Name
```

Comment: Though not the exact problem here this is also an issue with the code, so I don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: @MikeBrant Eh,i don't even care to ask anymore.Some people come home and kick the dog others down vote on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MySQL is dead. Use MySQLI or PDO instead. They are so much faster. Second of all, you're closing your MySQL connection after the echo:

```
echo "Current No. of registered Teams: " . $total1;
mysql_close($con); // <----- here 
?>
```

Before you actually finish all your PHP script.